# Bootstrap not loading properly for responsive navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a navbar using bootstrap and my responsive dropdown button isn't working. I don't know if its a problem with my code or a problem with the source links I'm using but I've rewritten this code 8 different ways and I get nothing. I used the following source links to get the bootstrap functionality. Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"/>

<button type="button" class="navebar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target=".dropdown-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
  <li class="dropdown">activity<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a></li>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar nav" aria-labelledby="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#recent activity">forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#member forum">login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#member list">sign up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#member group">chat</a></li>   
    </ul>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Try adding http: to the // in the two lines and see what you get

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: It's not clear as to what you are trying to do: possibly refer back to the Documentation for a default [Bootstrap Nav](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

Comment: I added the http and still nothing.

Comment: Your code is a very strange. I recommend to use documentation: 1)  [Bootstrap links](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn); 2) [default navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default); 3) [button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single).

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky the documentation was a large help. I was able to get the drop down to work it was a mistake in the HTML code not the links like I had originally thought. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you refer to jQuery before adding Bootstrap js file ?

**Update 1**: Mate, why you use link tag to js file, it must be script tag

Please change your code as below and see the result, I added jQuery before bootstrap-dropdown.js as well.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Update 2: I found your code have some issues. Please try the following.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Activity <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#recent activity">forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#member forum">login</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#member list">sign up</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#member group">chat</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not, I am unsure what to refer to. I was told the bootstrap link was all I needed.

Comment: I updated my answer Zuk, please try and let me know.

Comment: I changed to this and I got nothing. my home button also stopped working.

Comment: I got the home button fixed but still have no dropdown

Comment: You insight was a large help as well to the documentation about. After adding what you suggested and changing some things found different in the documentation above the drop down works! thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome Zuk. Next time when you work with Bootstrap, remember try copying their code first, then modify with your additional styling.